# Bypassing @font-face declaration that overrides "helvetica" font family

Tags: css, font-face, bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet that inserts a widget into any site's pages. The styling of the widget is being broken by a certain site that has the following CSS `@font-face` declaration:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "helvetica";
    src: url("http://cdn2.yoox.biz/Os/fonts/helveticaneueltstdmdcn.eot?iefix") format("eot"),
         url("http://cdn2.yoox.biz/Os/fonts/helveticaneueltstdmdcn.woff") format("woff"),
         url("http://cdn2.yoox.biz/Os/fonts/helveticaneueltstdmdcn.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("http://cdn2.yoox.biz/Os/fonts/helveticaneueltstdmdcn.svg#svgFontName") format("svg");
}
```

The widget that my bookmarklet inserts uses helvetica everywhere and on this one site it looks horrible because the browser is mapping helvetica to the `@font-face` declaration of that name rather than the standard helvetica system font.

The question: is there any way to override/bypass this `@font-face` declaration or create another `@font-face` declaration that maps to the system helvetica font?

Comment: @PerSalbark: It would be removed before you could blink :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless the stylesheet overrides it by referencing the stylesheet with `!important` after your widget's stylesheet, this could work:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ProperHelvetica'; /* Make a name for the "proper" Helvetica */
    src: local('helvetica'); /* Assign it to the Helvetica font on the user's system */
}
.your-widget {
    font-family: 'ProperHelvetica', helvetica, sans-serif !important; /* Make everything 
in your widget use the "proper" Helvetica and if the user doesn't have it,
use the site's helvetica. */
}
```

Comment: Even though I answered my own question, I will accept yours since it was the first non-self posted solution =)

Answer (score 4):

You can add the following css to create a custom font name that maps to a local installed font:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: mycustomuniquefontname;
    src: local("Helvetica");
}
```

For the styling of the widget you should use this:

```
font-family: mycustomuniquefontname, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

If you are using more font styles such as bold and italic, you have to define all of them:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: mycustomuniquefontname;
    src: local("Helvetica");
}
@font-face{
    font-family: mycustomuniquefontname;
    src: local("Helvetica Bold");
    font-weight: bold;
}
@font-face{
    font-family: mycustomuniquefontname;
    src: local("Helvetica Italic");
    font-style: italic;
}
@font-face{
    font-family: mycustomuniquefontname;
    src: local("Helvetica Bold Italic");
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As soon as I submitted this question I got some inspiration. What I found works is the following...

Create a the following css rule:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'RealHelvetica';
    src: local('helvetica');
}
```

In the elements that require the real helvetica system font specify the font-family as 'RealHelvetica' instead of just helvetica:

```
.widget {
    font-family: 'RealHelvetica',helvetica,sans-serif !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your widget in an iframe. Don't know if it the best solution, but it is *a* solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/bwcNX/

```
var $frame = $('<iframe style="width:200px; height:100px;">');
$('body').append( $frame );
setTimeout( function() {
    var $doc = $($frame[0].contentWindow.document.documentElement);
    $doc.html("<head><title>abc</title></head><body><div>def.</div></body></html>");
    $doc.find('div').append('<div>ghi.</div>');
}, 1 );
```

Bonus: Should future proof your widget against most other CSS or font related problems.

Comment: Excellent point but the functionality/interaction of my widget precludes using an iFrame. In general, that would be viable option.